# Method doesn't increment Values of Mapset properly

Tags: java, dictionary, hashset

My method is still producing the wrong values in my MapSet. The idea is to increment each key's (char) value by the number of times the character is spit out by the input stream. If the key doesn't already exist then it is added to the mapset and set to 1.

```
public static Map<Character, Integer> getCounts(FileInputStream input) throws IOException{ 
    Integer plusOne = 1;
    Map<Character, Integer> charCount = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

    while(input.read() >= 0){
        Character aByte = (char) input.read();
              if(charCount.containsKey(aByte)){
        System.out.println(aByte);
        charCount.put(aByte, charCount.get(aByte)+plusOne);
            }
        else
        charCount.put(aByte, 1);
        }
        return charCount;    
}
```

This is what the test file consists of: This is a bunch of text. Click save. Click save..

And these are my results: {f=0,  =2, c=0, C=1, .=2, k=1, h=0, i=2, ?=0, v=1, u=0, t=0, s=2, x=0}

This is my test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    FileInputStream test = new FileInputStream(new File("BunchofText.txt"));
    System.out.println(HuffmanNode.getCounts(test));
}
```

Any ideas where my code is faulty?

Nick -

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Yea yea, there's something wrong with setting the value associated with each key still.. I can't find any other methods to use and based on the Map api it doesn't look like there's anything wrong here

Comment: In the debugger, what do you see when you inspect the values for the arguments to your `put()` calls?

Answer (score 2):

You are throwing away half of the input stream by calling `input.read()` in the while loop's guard clause: the call consumes a character. You have to remember the character like this:

```
int b;
while( (b= input.read()) >= 0) {
  Character aByte = (char) b;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one call to input.read() method in the while loop and other call to get character from the stream, this in turn skips one character every time..

So to solve this you can either use

`int intInput = 0;
 while( (intInput = input.read()) >=0 ){
   Character aByte = (char)intInput;
    your code as it is ....
 }`